# Javascript fatal error when trying to run PHP file

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I am new to Javascript/HTML/CSS/PHP and I want to make a small survey page. I am unable to get my code running, could you please explain to me how I can make it work?

What I tried is to put HTML tags by running Javascript code. Also, I want to add buttons to save input from a text field to a file for a later analysis of how many people answered with which question. For example: 4 questions, 5 options each (a,b,c,d,e) makes 4 lines in file (e.g. a is chosen then 1,0,0,0,0).

Here is what I have tried so far: (its far from what I want, but I can't even make that run).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Fragebogen</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <article title="test">
        <footer>
            <div class="left">
                <button>OK</button>
            </div>
            <div class="right">
                <button>Abbrechen</button>
            </div>
        </footer>
    </article>
    <?php
    echo
        "<script type='text/javascript'>
            let labels = ['Vorname', 'Nachname', 'Alter', 'Geschlecht'];
            let section = document.querySelector('section.Labels');
            let str = Array();
            labels.forEach((item, i) => {
                str[i] =  `<label for='${item.value}'>${item.value}</label>`
            })

            section.innerHTML = str.join('</br>')
        </script>"
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Running this gives the following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Undefined constant "item" in C:\xampp\htdocs\Uni\Übung\Testat2\Test.php:27
> Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Uni\Übung\Testat2\Test>.php on line 27

Comment: Why is PHP even involved in this? Why isn't this script just directly added to HTML?

Comment: @El_Vanja this was just an example, as they stated it's not complete code.

Comment: @vanowm Sure, it says _"its far from what i want"_, but nothing in that description of what they want to do indicates the need for PHP. Either way, if any part of that script needs to be output by PHP, then it is far more sensible to only output those bits with PHP, rather than the entire script.

Answer (score 2):

Php recognizes the `"${}"` as a php variable because of the double quotes...

Maybe `\$` this would work.

Or change the `echo "..."` to single quotes `echo '...'` and change the inside single quotes for double quotes.